# How to calculate mean value of values on column which go comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe:

```
id   value
a1   1,2
b2   4
c1   NaN
c5   9,10,11
```

I want to create a new column mean_value which is equal to mean values in column value:

```
id   value     mean_value
a1   1,2          1.5
b2   4            4
c5   9,10,11      10
```

and I also want to remove those values in NaN in it. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `str.split` and `mean`:

```
df = df.assign(mean_value=df['value'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
               .mean(axis=1)).dropna()
```

Output:

```
   id    value  mean_value
0  a1      1,2         1.5
1  b2        4         4.0
3  c5  9,10,11        10.0
```